# javascript not reading input text value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a html page and populate with a text input and a textarea via an ajax call. When I try reading the values in a javascript function I get empty, I am guessing it is reading the original values when it was populated as empty but strangely when I run a loop I get the value.

Working with the textarea only.
It is populated in the page as

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="txtBody"></textarea>
```

and I type in My value

when I run the function called from a button

```
function testValues(){
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
   for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
       console.log(i + " - " + elements[i].id + " -- " + elements[i].value);
    }
}
```

I get this output

0 - txtBody --

1 - txtBody -- My value

Solved
Thank you to everyone and as you can see it was showing that the elements were duplicated.
Just to explain I do an ajax call and my php returns a xml page that I use javascript to read and populate my html page.
Normally this works well but while going through the javascript function wanting to post the relevant parts here I realised that there was a duplicate in populating the output into my html page hence I was getting two of each element.

Comment: You should add the ajax call, and the function that shows the old values

Comment: Please edit your question and use the `[<>]` snippet button to include a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another "textarea" element in your page ?

Comment: Post the code that gets the wrong result, not the code that returns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two textareas on your page. Both of them has the `id` of `txtBody`. If you run

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").length);
```

you will get a two as a result.

Btw, ids should be unique.

Comment: Thank you and yes I found my fault populating the html page twice .. :(

Comment: @Simon happy to help. If this answer solved your problem, then you might accept it as the correct answer.